# Execute a command within 'sed'

Tags: sed, regular-expression, perl

I have a list of random memory addresses saved in a text file, and I need to `sed` them out, decode them, and save them back to my file. However, the decoding operation I'm trying to perform is handled in a C++ program I've created some time ago. The problem I am encountering now is executing the C++ within the `sed` command; that is, I want to back-reference the part that needs to be decoded and use it as an argument in my C++ program. I have written the following command:

```
cat $1 | sed -r 's/(0[Xx])([0-9A-Za-z]{1,8})/\1`./convAddrs \2`/g';
```

before I had the chance to read an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355443/using-command-substitution-inside-a-sed-script-with-arguments) post saying that `sed` does NOT execute commands. Is it true that `sed` doesn't allow the execution of commands? If so, assuming the command I've written is a valid `sed` sequence, how would I write it in `perl`?

Comment: link added. my bad :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's|(?<=0x)[0-9a-f]{1,8}|`./convAddrs $&`|gei'
```

- `perl -pe`: like `sed`: process the input one line at a time in `$_`, evaluate the perl [e]xpression passed to `-e` for each line and [p]rint the modified `$_` for each.
- `s|X|Y|gei`: substitute `Y` for `X` in `$_` ([g]lobally, case [i]nsensitively, and treating `Y` as a perl [e]xpression instead of a basic string).
- `(?<=0x)`: look behind for `0x`.
- `[0-9a-f]{1,8}`: one to 8 hex digits, as many as possible
- `` `./convAddrs $&` ``: replace by the output of that shell command line where `$&` is replaced by the matched part.

Comment: I'm getting the following error when executing your command:
Having no space between pattern and following word is deprecated at -e line 1.
Regexp modifiers "/a" and "/d" are mutually exclusive at -e line 1, at end of line
Regexp modifiers "/a" and "/d" are mutually exclusive at -e line 1, at end of line
Can't find string terminator "`" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.

Comment: Of course, sorry my bad, you need to change the separator as we can't use `/` here since it's used inside the replacement part. Corrected.

Comment: Damn, and I though that _I_ was pretty good at Perl one liners, +1!

Answer (score 3):

It may or may not be true that `sed` cannot execute commands. It is *not* true of a GNU `sed`:

```
sed -Ee 's/(0[Xx])([0-9A-Za-z]{1,8})/\1\n ./convAddrs \2\n#/g' \
-eh -e  's/\n.//gp;g;s/^/#/e' <"$1"
```

It's unclear to me exactly what else might be in your `<$1` input, and so i take care to `#` comment out anything which is not `command \2` in the pattern space. When you use GNU's `e`xecute flag on a `s///`ubstitution it passes the entire resulting pattern space to `$SHELL -c` as its second argument, and then subsequently replaces all of pattern-space with whatever is written to that `$SHELL`'s stdout. So I above I print whatever your results were before first, and then after the results of passing the command-line to the shell.