# Expand placeholders with same-named environment vars in text file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, pipe

There are a lot of variations on this question, but I wanted to ask it here anyways because I am so close (!) to finding a solution on this one - I just need a little nudge.

### Scenario

I have several text SQL files that I use to run reports on a Postgres database hosted with Heroku. One of the SQL files currently looks like this:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metrics WHERE(organization_id = o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS metrics,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_metrics WHERE(organization_id = o.id)) AS quarterly_metrics,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quarterly_metrics WHERE(organization_id = o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS quarterly_metrics,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quarterly_text_metrics WHERE(organization_id = o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS quarterly_text_metrics,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM budgets WHERE(organization_id = o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS budgets,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM goals WHERE(goalable_type = 'Organization' AND goalable_id = o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS goals
FROM
  organizations AS o
WHERE
  o.id = ${sql_org_id}
;
```

I would **like** to use a process like this:

```
export sql_org_id=1; export sql_year=2013
cat reports/my_report.sql | sed -e "s/\(\${[a-zA-Z_]*}\)/`eval "echo '\1'"`/" | heroku pg:psql
```

So that I can just pipe the SQL to Heroku for the report, replacing all the variables with their corresponding ENV vars that were exported just before running the script (so that I can simply change the variables on the fly and run additional reports instead of editing the SQL file).

### My Problem

So the issue is that I am **almost** there, but I can't quite get it. The `sed` expression I have works when I use `echo` like this:

```
export sql_year=2013
echo "SELECT ${sql_year} AS year" | sed -e "s/\(\${[a-zA-Z_]*}\)/`eval "echo '\1'"`/"
```

But I can't get it to work with `cat` on the entire file contents:

```
export sql_org_id=1; export sql_year=2013
cat reports/my_report.sql | sed -e "s/\(\${[a-zA-Z_]*}\)/`eval "echo '\1'"`/"
```

Am I missing something when using `sed` with `cat`? Please help!

**UPDATE:** I am on Mac OS X 10.8

Comment: Have you tried abandoning `cat` altogether and just using the `sed -e 'expression_here' file_name` syntax? You're guilty of a [useless use of cat](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpartmaps.org%2Fera%2Funix%2Faward.html&ei=iZ35UabpK-aT4AS18YHIAg&usg=AFQjCNHW_M9kdNkyIeaOdC9Rcdb5668lKg&sig2=HjjLG2YL0ryi7dTcw5GhTQ&bvm=bv.49967636,d.bGE) there. Also, it may not be necessary with the particular example you specified but semantically, I think you need a `g` modifier on your `sed` regex.

Comment: I don't think you can execute code inside of a `sed` either. It was covered earlier in this question today: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85082/execute-a-command-within-sed

Comment: @slm: You can execute code inside of a sed. Try `echo foo | sed "s/foo/$(uptime)/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `zsh`:

```
print -r -- "${(e)$(<reports/my_report.sql)}"
```

With any Bourne-like shell (including `zsh`):

```
eval "cat << EOF
$(cat reports/my_report.sql)
EOF"
```

Both will expand all the `` `...` ``, `$(...)`, `$((...))`, `$[...]`, `$xxx` and `${xxx}`. So you'll need to escape the dollar and backtick characters you don't want expanded.

In addition, for the second one, the content of the file must not contain a line consisting of the three characters `EOF` (which for `SQL` shouldn't be a problem).

Alternatively, you could do:

```
perl -pe 's/\${(\w+)}/$ENV{$1}/g' reports/my_report.sql
```

You'll need to `export` the variables, for `perl` to be aware of them.

As to why your solution doesn't work and is not anywhere near working, you can run it after `set -x` to see what's going on:

```
$ echo "SELECT ${sql_year} AS year" | sed -e "s/\(\${[a-zA-Z_]*}\)/`eval "echo '\1'"`/"
+ echo 'SELECT 2013 AS year'
++ eval 'echo '\''\1'\'''
+++ echo '\1'
+ sed -e 's/\(${[a-zA-Z_]*}\)/\1/'
SELECT 2013 AS year
```

By using double quotes, the shell expands the variables and command substitution before calling `echo` and `sed`. So, you actually ran:

```
echo 'SELECT 2013 AS year' | sed -e 's/\(${[a-zA-Z_]*}\)/\1/'
```

`sed` cannot execute code. So even if you had used single quotes, `sed` would not have expanded the `` `...` ``.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer and explanation on what's actually going on. I decided to go with the `perl` solution because it is much more likely to be the same no matter which system it is run on.

Answer (score 1):

I would let Bash interpolate the values for you instead of trying to write a regular expression to do the same (or leverage some templating system).

```
echo $(eval echo $(cat sql.sql))
```

Where sql.sql contains a valid bash string (so encase it in double quotes):

```
"SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metrics WHERE(organization_id = o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS metrics,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_metrics WHERE(organization_id = o.id)) AS quarterly_metrics,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quarterly_metrics WHERE(organization_id = o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS quarterly_metrics,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quarterly_text_metrics WHERE(organization_id = o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS quarterly_text_metrics,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM budgets WHERE(organization_id = o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS budgets,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM goals WHERE(goalable_type = 'Organization' AND goalable_id =     o.id AND year = ${sql_year})) AS goals
FROM
  organizations AS o
WHERE
  o.id = ${sql_org_id}
;"
```

Comment: I tried this approach too, but I use `zsh`, and I get the following error: `zsh: no matches found: (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM metrics WHERE(organization_id = o.id AND year = 2013))`

Answer (score 0):

What if you change your approach around so that you do this instead:

```
$ heroku pg:psql --app app_name < file.sql
```